# Monitoring cisco devices from linux or windows?

Tags: cisco

how can i know the status of a large no of devices (approx 600,000).If i want to moniter the status of the device whether up or down.

Will any scripting language be sutable for such a task because the only way i can think of monitoring these devices from a linux/windows machine is to ping the device status.but again pinging will not be a good idea beacuse it will take a lot of time.

If i need to login and check the status of ports then that would take a lot more time.

what is the best way possible?
How many devices can i ping if i use parralell processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at, and investigate System Management solutions such as Nagios, Tivoli Netview, , etc.

If you have to manage 600,000 devices, then I presume you've got a decent budget.